# SimpleCursorAdapter with TextView and compound drawables

Tags: android, android-adapter

Is possible to use a `TextView` + `Drawable` Compound with `SimpleCursorAdapter` ?

I'm getting the warning: *This tag and its children can be replaced by one `<TextView/>` and a compound drawable* and, I don't know how to fix this using `SimpleCursorAdapter`.

1. My previous code:

   ```
   convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_group, null);
   ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text)).setText(item.getName());
   ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text)).setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(item.getIcon(), 0, 0, 0);
   ```
2. My current code:

   ```
   mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getBaseContext(),
           R.layout.list_item_group,
           null,
           new String[] { DataBaseHelper.KEY_NAME},
           new int[] { R.id.name }, 0);        

   mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
   ```

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

if you want to have compounddrawables in your simplecursoradapter, you can extend the SimpleCursorAdapter and override setViewText(TextView, String)

Comment: I solved this creating the setViewValue method implementing ViewBinder, it's a correct solution? Tks